# Passing by reference in PHP

Tags: php

I have a bit of a general dissatisfaction about the way passing by reference works in PHP, coming from a Java background myself. This might have been talked about before on SO, so I'm sorry if this might seem redundant.

I'm going to give a code example to make things clear. Say we have a Person class:

```
<?php

class Person 
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

?>
```

and the following usage:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/Person.php';

function changeName(Person $person)
{
    $person->setName("Michael");
}

function changePerson(Person $person)
{
    $person = new Person("Jerry");
}

$person = new Person("John");

changeName($person);
echo $person->getName() . PHP_EOL;

changePerson($person);
echo $person->getName() . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Now I, and many others coming from programming in Java or C# into PHP, would expect the above code to output:

```
Michael
Jerry
```

However, it does not, it outputs:

```
Michael
Michael
```

I know it can be fixed by using &. From looking into it, I understand that this is because the reference is passed into the function by value (a copy of the reference). But this to me constitutes an unexpected / inconsistent behavior, so the question would be: Is there any particular reason or benefit for which they chose to do it this way?

Comment: How does `&` "constitute an unexpected / inconsistent behavior"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat "Unexpected" for someone used to Java's pass-by-reference.  I believe OP is referring to how only one of the functions outputs what he expected.

Comment: @Vulcan: That would make sense, I guess.  PHP is just a different language, with different rules :-P

Comment: *Both* the functions you've defined pass by value, the return should be `John John`, not `Michael Michael`.

Comment: As stated at php.net: `A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.`

Comment: @Sammitch: http://ideone.com/JoANu2

Comment: @RocketHazmat that's messed up. But I guess I shouldn't be shocked that PHP is inconsistent.

Comment: @Sammitch: It's not "inconsistent".  Objects are *always* passed by reference in PHP.  In `changePerson`, you are *replacing* the local variable, instead of updating the reference.  You need the `&` to update the reference. :-)

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: No, they are not. That's an overstatement, as you can see in the link provided in shadyyx's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would work as expected if used this way:

```
function changePerson(Person &$person) // <- & to state the reference
{
    $person = new Person("Jerry");
}

$person = new Person("John");

changeName($person);
echo $person->getName() . PHP_EOL;

changePerson($person);
echo $person->getName() . PHP_EOL;
```

See the output: http://codepad.org/eSt4Xcpr

> One of the key-points of PHP 5 OOP that is often mentioned is that "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true.
>
> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

Quoted from http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php.

Comment: Yes, your second link, and particularly that second paragraph (which should be pasted entirely in your answer imo), made things a lot more clear. "objects are passed by references" is just an overstatement of what php really does. Fwiw, I knew how to avoid the situation, as I stated in my original post. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The second paragraph is cited as a comment to Your question so I didn't feel I have to cite it again :-), anyway, You are welcome!

Comment: This answer does not even attempt to explain the ***why*** of the situation :/

Comment: @Leigh The why is explained at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php.

Comment: It's true it doesn't address the reason why they might have chosen this approach, but that could be something very few people might know. :)

Answer (score 2):

The object itself is actually passed by reference, otherwise your first `echo` would not output `Michael`.

What happens in your second example is that you destroy the (local) reference to the original object and have your variable name reference a new object that has a local scope in the function.

That makes sense to me as you could destroy / replace your object with something completely different by simply assigning a new value to the variable in the function.

Comment: I really don't think that's the expected behavior when passing by reference (speaking in general terms, not php particularly). Objects assigned to references shouldn't lose scope when exiting that function. I think shadyyx, with his second link, makes things a bit clear, in that references in php aren't real references. See the second paragraph in his link.

Comment: Almost correct (I believe) it's not to do with the scope, but more to do with when you create a new reference, the storage variable is kind of "recreated" (and I'm explaining what I mean badly...). Take for example `$a = &$b; $b = &$c; $c= 'hello'; var_dump($a, $b, $c);` - The output will show `$a` as null, because `$b` was "reallocated" as a reference itself, $a points to the "old" `$b` while `$b` itself is the "new" one. All of those variables are in the same scope.